# For master rule 4, why can't I occupy two extra monster zone?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I am a beginner at the Yugioh card game. I use sky strikers. Based on the link monster, I can summon the monster from the extra deck to the place where the monster point. Here is a figure:
[image: screen shot of the user attempting to do as their question states]

However, I cannot do this in my practice. Am I  missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For balance reasons, Konami introduced a special rule for the second extra monster zone.
It is possible to occupy both, but only under certain circumstances. Just having a link monster point there is insufficient.

To occupy the second extra zone you need what is called an extra link. This means having monsters co-linked from one extra monster zone all the way to the other.

You can find this illustrated here:
https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Extra_Link

Comment: Theoretically it is possible with a minimum of 3 monsters, but Konami has been very careful not to print any cards with double forward diagonal arrows with which this can happen.